# How can I extract the original image stream from a System.Drawing.Bitmap object?

Tags: c#, resources, resx, system.drawing

I am embedding images into my assembly using `.resx` files. Upon runtime, I need to save the images into standalone files, restoring the original content. How can I extract the original file stream from an `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instance? I know I can create a stream using `Bitmap.Save()`, but this transcodes (and in effect - inflates) the images, even when saving a PNG back as PNG.

Or perhaps my mistake is reading them from `Resource` as `Bitmap` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you have read it as a `Bitmap` object, you can't get the original file stream back. The `Bitmap` object only contains the uncompressed data, not the original data.

You should read the resource as byte data intead. You can read from the resource stream and write to a file:

```
using (Stream source = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.filename.jpg")) {
  using (FileStream dest = File.Create(fileName)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while (true) {
      int len = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      if (len == 0) break;
      dest.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this requires adding the image as an *embedded* resource, not a *managed* resource. You can create an `Image` from it using `Image.FromStream()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the problem.  PNG is a loss-less format, you'll get the exact same image back.  Yes, you don't necessarily get the exact same bytes when you Save().  It is a compressed format and the amount of time spent by the compressor on getting the best balance between compression and speed might not be the same.  But, so what?

If it is a real problem then you shouldn't add the image as a managed resource.  You can add it to your project as an embedded resource and read it from the metadata with Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream().  You'll get the raw image file bytes.  Convertible to an Image with Image.FromStream().

Comment: I'm also storing .jpg and .gif, and the image files are optimized quite heavily by the graphics designer. But the solution I use now (and which works) is based on embedded resources instead of managed, and as you wrote - this works.

Answer (score 1):

[HOW TO: Load a Bitmap or Image from a Resource by Using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324567)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not actually using the `Bitmap` for display purposes in your appliction (i.e. you're just extracting the resource as a bitmap so you can save it as a file), then the simplest approach is to just get the resource as a `Stream` and save it to a file.

This tutorial shows how to get resources as streams:

http://devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=75

In the sample, the author gets a stream and passes it to the `Bitmap.FromStream` method.  What you would do instead is just save that stream directly to a file (bypassing `Bitmap` entirely).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was in using managed resources - resx builder creates **Bitmap** objects from image files and serializes those objects, it **does not store the original file stream**. However, embedded resources can store flat binary files.

I am now embedding all files from my images folder using the following `.csproj` entries:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Images\*.jpg" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Images\*.png" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Images\*.gif" />
```

Visual Studio shows them as normal in-project files with `Build Action` set to `Embedded Resource`.

Then, from my code, I load the original file streams with:

```
var assembly = GetType().Assembly;
var regex = new Regex("\\.(png|jpg|gif))$");
foreach (var bitmap in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
  if(!regex.IsMatch(bitmap)
    continue;

  var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(bitmap);
  //handle the stream here
}
```